# Get the highest number of the array

Tags: perl

I have a file which contain 2 x 2 arrays.

data

```
1: 6.1703
541.631 46.0391

2: 6.1930
537.446 45.9239

3: 6.1931
177.171 288.579

4: 6.1939
167.171 298.579

5: 8.2281
 533.686 53.7245

6: 8.6437
519.219 65.0547

7: 9.0823
484.191 95.0753

8: 9.3884
 237.75 240.082

9: 9.4701
 167.525 246.234

10: 9.7268
 411.929 70.7877
```

I need to see the value of the position (1,2) of each matrix, and choose it if it is near to 6.1937 and has a large value in the element(2,1). In this example the chosen value should be 6.1930. (THIS PART IS SOLVED IN [How to record numbers of array elements based on selection comparision criteria](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289908/13792))

Second, I need to choose the highest value of the position (2,2) of each matrix, and then print the corresponding (1,2) element.In this case, the chosen value is 6.1939 (THIS PART NEED TO BE MODIFIED IN THE SCRIPT)

The solution were posted for a similar question before:

Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $close_to = 6.1937;

my ($close, $lowest);

$/ = q();
while (<>) {
    my @arr = split;
    if ((! defined $close || abs($arr[1] - $close_to) < abs($close - $close_to))
        && $arr[2] > $arr[3]
        ) {
        $close = $arr[1];
    }
    if ((! defined $lowest || $arr[1] < $lowest)
        && $arr[2] < $arr[3]
        ) {
        $lowest = $arr[1];
    }
    if (eof) {
        print "$close $lowest\n";
        undef $close;
        undef $lowest;
    }
}
```

I think that a modification need to be done in this part of the script but I do not how to do that.

```
if ((! defined $lowest || $arr[1] < $lowest)
       && $arr[2] < $arr[3]
        ) {
       $lowest = $arr[1];
}
```

The output to the data must be:

```
6.1930  6.1939
```

Comment: Please, re-read the explanation paragraph and rewrite it so it makes sense. I have no clue what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to change that part of the code. The problem is you now need to store two values: the highest value found so far, and the corresponding (1,2) element.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $close_to = 6.1937;

my ($close, $highest, $corr_highest);

$/ = q();
while (<>) {
    my @arr = split;
    if ((! defined $close || abs($arr[1] - $close_to) < abs($close - $close_to))
        && $arr[2] > $arr[3]
        ) {
        $close = $arr[1];
    }
    if (! defined $highest || $arr[3] > $highest) {
        ($highest, $corr_highest) = @arr[3, 1];

    }
    if (eof) {
        print "$close $corr_highest\n";
        undef $_ for $close, $highest, $corr_highest;
    }
}
```